# How to align linear layout with gridview at the center of screen?

Tags: android

I am having a `gridView` in `linearLayout` and I want align it in the center of the screen below code is not giving center alignment here is the screen short. I want complete `gridView` in the middle of screen.

[image]

**Layout XML:**

```
 <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#000000" >

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg"  
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"  >

  <GridView
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/grid" />

 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: place `android:gravity="center"` in `<LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:numColumns="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am getting it in the center but I want to use below space also which is going waste. I am getting output like this http://s13.postimg.org/7h0gjdncn/image.png

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000">

  <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/bg"  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"  >

<GridView
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/grid"

         />



     </LinearLayout>
         </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
    android:weightSum="1">

    <GridView
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```